# Relative interior point in an open disc

Tags: complex-analysis, euclidean-geometry

I'm having  a problem in solving the following, but I don't know how I can proceed to proof.

Let be $z\in D_R(c)$ where $D_R(c)$ is an open disc with radius $R>0 $ and  center $c\in \mathbb{C}, $ and $R\neq |c|.$  Then how to establish $\frac{(|c|^2-R^2)}{\bar{x}}\in D_R(c)?$

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is $D_R(c)$? Is it the disc of radius $R$ centered in$c$?

Comment: Alain Remillard Yes!